# Mongo Search on Two Fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

What is  the best way to write a query to  search on mongo  on two fields like first_name and last_name with a single query string separated by a space ?

Also the query string may or may not contain the last_name

```js
var query = req.params.searchtext

User.find({
  first_name: query,
  last_name: query
})
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Ask a clear question with a clear example of the code ( even if not working ) that you are trying to achieve. Many ways to interpret your feeble one sentence question. Try better. Use the **edit** link on your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Okay this seems like normal JavaScript stuff to me. How to "split" a string on a "space" between two words:

```
var string = "Hello World";
var parts = string.split(" ");
```

Which yields for `parts`:

```
["Hello", "World"]
```

So simply using array notation:

```
User.find({
    first_name: parts[0],
    last_name: parts[1]
})
```